# Pulling data from fullcalendar

Tags: php, jquery, fullcalendar

I went through all 1743 questions about fullcalendar and I noticed there are a lot of questions regarding loading events from json, php or mysql into the calendar, 
but no one ever asked how to do the opposite.

So, my question is how can I pull data about the event objects in the fullcalendar and use it.

My goal is to insert the calendar's data into a mysql DB, but a small direction on how to 'get' to the data will be enough for me to start.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if I've understood you clearly, but if you wish to retrieve the events in a calendar you can simply use the function clientEvents.

```
$('#your-selector').fullCalendar('clientEvents', function(ev) {
     //will loop for each event you have in the calendar
     console.log(ev); //event
});
```

You might check out fullcalendar's documentation as well

http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/clientEvents/

Regards,

Comment: yeah that should do the trick.
I guess I didn't notice that in the documentation.

tnx